# Why is MySQL is changing its timezone between calls?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I create a couple stored procedures to save some data into my development database, just to see something weird happening.

During the first calls, around 2 or 3, the entry is registered with my local time.
However, a couple minutes later, when calling the SP again, I realized that the entries were being registered with a -03:00:00 difference with my local time.

E.g.:

- I run the SP, entry is registered with time 11:19
- I run the SP again, entry is registered with time 11:19
- I run the SP yet again, but now the entry is registered with time 8:20

And after that all entries gets registered with -3 hours from my local time.

Has anyone ever experienced that? I am not sure what could have happened in between those calls, as far as I know, no other procedure should've been called.

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

**Edit (adding code)**

This is the code of a function we use instead of now()

```
CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'America/New_York')
```

Calling it once returns the expected result, a couple minutes/calls later, different time.

**Solution (in case anyone goes through this)**

Didn't know that the first timestamp of a table, unless otherwise explicit, will by default be 
`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
As on an update this would override our custom function for defining the date and using the date without the timestamp, hence the difference between dates.

Docs for reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Telepathy offline, post code instead.

Comment: Well, this is not a coding issue, since in other environments it works as expected, that's why I didn't bother with any code

Comment: found the culprit, updating question.